# Stata Misreading Time Variables - How to Change These?

Tags: time, stata, minute

I've got sports data that I've imported from an online source via a .xlsx file. Each observation is a penalty in an NFL (American football) game. In order to later `merge` this with another dataset, I need to have certain variables/values that match up between the two files. I'm hitting an issue with one variable, however.

In the main dataset in question (the penalty dataset originally mentioned), my ultimate goal is to create two variables, `Minute` and `Second`, that are of type `byte` and `format %8.0g`. This would make them perfectly correspond with the respective variables in the destination dataset. I have the required information available, which is the time remaining in the given quarter of the NFL game, but it's stored in a strange way, and I'm having trouble converting things.

The data is stored in a variable called `Time`. Visibly, the data looks fine as imported from the original .xlsx file. For example, the first observation reads "12:21", indicating that there are 12 minutes and 21 seconds left in the quarter. When importing from the .xlsx sheet, however, Stata assumes that the variable `Time` is a date/time variable measured in hh:mm, and thus assigns it a type of `double` and a format of `%tchh:MM`.

In the end, I don't really care about correctly formatting this `Time` variable, but I need to somehow make this match the required `Minute` and `Second` columns of the destination file. I've tried several different approaches, but so far nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Stata is misreading minutes and seconds as hours and minutes, and also (as it does) storing date-times in milliseconds, then it is off by a factor of 60 (minutes/hour) x 1000 (ms/s) = 60000. So, consider

```
. clear 

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen double wrong = clock("1jan1960 12:21:00", "DMY hms") 

. format wrong %tchh:MM 

. clonevar alsowrong = wrong 

. format alsowrong %15.0f 

. list 

     +------------------+
     | wrong   alsowr~g |
     |------------------|
  1. | 12:21   44460000 |
     +------------------+

. gen right = wrong/60000

. gen byte Minute = floor(right/60) 

. gen byte Second = mod(right, 60) 

. list 

     +--------------------------------------------+
     | wrong   alsowr~g   right   Minute   Second |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. | 12:21   44460000     741       12       21 |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

I can't comment easily on your import, as neither imported file nor exact import code are given as examples.

EDIT Another way to do it:

```
. gen alsoright = string(wrong, "%tchh:MM")

. gen minute = real(substr(alsoright, 1, strpos(alsoright, ":") - 1))

. gen second = real(substr(alsoright, strpos(alsoright, ":") + 1, .))

. l alsoright minute second

     +----------------------------+
     | alsori~t   minute   second |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |    12:21       12       21 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! On my commute home last night, attempting something like your first solution came to my mind. If this hadn't been answered here, I would've tried that. I went with the second solution you mentioned (after the edit) since it was shorter, and it worked perfectly. I'd tried to do something like that yesterday, but I couldn't get the string variable ("alsoright") to read "12:21" rather than the underlying date/time number that Stata actually reads.

Thanks again for your help!